# How to convert SQL subquery to linq lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022, c#-6.0

I have following SQL subqueries and want to convert them to linq lambda.

Count:

```
select count(*)
from ParentA
where orderStatus in ('Status1','Status2')
  and orderNumer in (select orderNumber
                     from ChildB
                     where approval = 0)
```

Entities:

```
public class ParentA
{
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public ChildB Order { get; set; }
    public string orderStatus { get; set; }
    public long orderNumer { get; set; }
}

public class ChildB
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long orderNumer { get; set; }
    public bool approval { get; set;}
}
```

All columns:

```
select *
from ParentA
where orderStatus = 'Status1'
  and orderNumer in (select orderNumber
                     from ChildB
                     where approval = 1)
```

Eg:

```
var query =_dbcontext.ParentA.Include().Where().Count();
```

Comment: Its not clear how you wish your two queries to be combined. Maybe some sample data and desired result would help.

Comment: Those are separate queries ,one query for count of ParentA table and other query for all columns of ParentA table

Comment: Can you please add to your question an example of what properties the two entities have? Including any navigation properties. (If you don't know what that means, include anything from `ParentA` that is `virtual` or contains a collection of `ChildB`). If you do that, I can update my answer to be more in-line with what you can do in your code.

Comment: So, based on your entities, your schema is bad. `ParentA` which appears to be an order line item, should actually be the child record. `ChildB` which appears to be an actual order, should be the parent. There are many line items on an order, so you should have a collection navigation property on `ChildB` of `public virtual ICollection<ParentA> LineItems { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your posted classes, it looks more like ChildB is the parent and ParentA is the child, with one ChildB per ParentA.

The following should be the method LINQ equivalents:

```
var result1 = db.ParentA
    .Where(a =>
        (a.orderStatus == "Status1" || a.orderStatus == "Status2")
        && !a.ChildB.approval
    )
    .Count();

var result2 = db.ParentA
    .Where(a =>
        (a.orderStatus == "Status1")
        && a.ChildB.approval
    )
    .ToList();
```

If you ChildB class has a ParentA collection not shown in your post, this could also be written as:

```
var result1 = db.ChildB
    .Where(b => !b.approval)
    .SelectMany(b => b.ParentA
        .Where(a => a.orderStatus == "Status1" || a.orderStatus == "Status2")
    )
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
    
var result2 = db.ChildB
    .Where(b => b.approval)
    .SelectMany(b => b.ParentA
        .Where(a => a.orderStatus == "Status1")
    )
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough take of what you're looking for.

```
// Create a collection of some form with your statuses you want to check.
var statuses = new string[] {"Status1", "Status2"};

// Get your order numbers for the 'orderNumber in' portion of your query.
var orderNumbers = _dbcontext.ChildB.Where(x => x.approval == 0);

// Get the count using these collections.
var count = _dbcontext.ParentA.Where(x => statuses.Contains(x.orderStatus) && orderNumbers.Contains(x.orderNumber)).Count();

// Your 'All columns' query is slightly simpler, if you know you only need to filter by the one status instead of multiple...
var approvedOrderNumbers = _dbcontext.ChildB.Where(x => x.approval == 1);
var results = _dbcontext.ParentA.Where(x => x.orderStatus == "Status1" && approvedOrderNumbers.Contains(x.OrderNumber)).ToList();
```

Some things to note:

- If you have a navigation property between `ParentA` and `ChildB` (which any properly designed database/DbContext *should* have, the LINQ would look different.
- LINQ is always a little backwards from how SQL does `in`. As you can see, first you must build the collection you want to use for your `in` parameter, and then see if *it* contains the entity value.
- I wrote this code freehand in a text editor, and I never use string arrays so I'm not even sure if that's the proper syntax to initialize one.

Based on the confirmation that you have navigation properties on ParentA, here's an example of how to use those:

```
var statuses = new string[] {"Status1", "Status2"};

var count = _dbcontext.ParentA.Where(x => statuses.Contains(x.orderStatus) && x.ChildBs.Any(y => y.approval == 0)).Count();

var results = _dbcontext.ParentA.Where(x => x.orderStatus == "Status1" && x.ChildBs.Any(y => y.approval == 1)).ToList();
```

Some additional notes:

- If you were to share your actual goal, such as "Get the count of all the `ParentA`s where *all* of their `ChildB`s are approved," or, "Get all the columns from `ParentA` where *any* of their `ChildB`s are not approved," would allow us to better help you in writing the correct statements.
- As it stands, these queries will get you:

  - A set of `ParentA` that contain at least one `ChildB` with `approval` of 0.
  - A set of `ParentA` that contain at least one `ChildB` with `approval` of 1.

If that's not what you want, then you need to include in plain English what your result set should look like.

Comment: I have navigation property between ParentA and ChildB and using code first approach. Can't we get  count and all columns in single statement 
Eg:
var query =_dbcontext.ParantA.Include().Where().Count();?
In the above query you are fetching statuses first and then orderNumbers and then count.

Comment: The two queries you put in your question are in fact quite different, and therefore cannot be combined directly. Even without using `.Count()`, the datasets returned would be different. I will however add examples of how to do this using the navigation property on `ParentA`.

Comment: @user2580179 Also, I don't think you understand the purpose of `Include()`. It's not for joining data, but for forcing eager loading of navigation properties. It doesn't really apply to what you're asking.

Comment: @user2580179 Use the Edit link on your question, and place that inside a code block so that it can be properly formatted.

Comment: thank you for your time. just added image for the entities

Comment: @user2580179 Excellent. One last step. This is a classic [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I really want to help you get the results you're seeking, but I really need to know why you're trying to do these particular queries. What results are you expecting? What do you want to do with the data?